# Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove bernoullis inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove that if $p>1$ then $(1+x)^p>1+px$ for $x \in (-1,0)\cup (0,\infty)$

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? Can you state the mean value theorem, and think of a function that you might try applying it to?

Comment: i let $f(x)=(1+x)^p$ and by MVT there exists a c in the interval $(a,b) s.t f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$ What should i use for my b and a?

Comment: hint: rewrite the inequality as $(1 + x)^p - 1 > px$

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, actually I wrote the answer quickly and a bit carelessly ... but let's take a different path.

Let $f(x) = (1+x)^p$, and $g(x) = 1+px$; clearly $f'(x) = p(1+x)^{p-1}$ and $g'(x) = p$.

It means that $f'(x) > g'(x)$ for $x > 0$ ( because $1 + x > 1$), and $f(0) = g(0) = 1$, so $f(x) > g(x)$ for every $x > 0$.

Instead if $-1 < x < 0$, consider the function $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$: it's continuous (because it's the difference of 2 continuous functions) and

$$h'(x) = f'(x) - g'(x) = p(1+x)^{p-1} - p < 0 \text{ for every } x <0 \, (\text{because } 1 + x < 1).$$

It follows that $h(x)$ is continuous and monotonous; in particular $h(x)$ is a decreasing function, so in $(-1,0)$ its minimum value is $h(0) = 0$, instead for every $x$ such that $-1 < x <  0$

$h(x) > 0$, it implies that $h(x) = f(x) - g(x) > 0 \to f(x) > g(x)$ if $-1 < x < 0$, which proves the thesis.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try $f(x) = (1 + x)^{p}$ and then use $f(x) - f(0) = xf'(c)$. Clearly $f'(x) = p(1 + x)^{p - 1}$.

> If $x > 0$ then clearly we have $0 < c < x$ and therefore $(1 + c) > 1$ and that implies $f'(c) = p(1 + c)^{p - 1} > p$ so that $f(x) - f(0) = xf'(c) > px$. If $-1 < x < 0$ then $-1 < x < c < 0$ so that $0 < (1 + c) < 1$ and hence $f'(c) = p(1 + c)^{p - 1} < p$. Since $x < 0$ we get $xf'(c) > px$ and thus we get $f(x) - f(0) > px$ in this case also. Since $f(0) = 1$ it follows that we have $(1 + x)^{p} = f(x) > 1 + px$ for all $x \in (-1, 0)\cup(0, \infty)$.